# I want to group My array according to week in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$date = array('01-01-2019','02-01-2019','05-01-2019','22-01-2019','02-02-2019','03-02-2019','24-02-2019');
```

Above is my array, I want to group the dates according to week so I can show them properly in reports. So it will be like this:

```
Array
(
    [31-12-2018/06-01-2019] => Array  // this is based in calendar week
        (
            [0] => 01-01-2019
            [1] => 02-01-2019
            [2] => 05-01-2019
        )

    [21-01-2019/27-01-2019] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22-01-2019
        )

    [28-01-2019/03-02-2019] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02-02-2019
            [1] => 03-02-2019
        )

    [18-02-2019/24-02-2019] =>  Array
    (
        [0] => 24-02-2019
    )
)
```

> this are based on calendar week from Monday to Sunday
>   [image]

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: Hint: you can use `date('W', strtotime($oneDate))` to get a week number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do what you want. It converts each date value to a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, finds the start and end of week for that date, and then pushes the value into a new array indexed by the start & end of week values:

```
$date = array('01-01-2019','02-01-2019','05-01-2019','22-01-2019','02-02-2019','03-02-2019','24-02-2019');
$dates = array();
foreach ($date as $d) {
    $od = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y', $d);
    // get start and end of this week
    $sow = $od->sub(new DateInterval('P' . ($od->format('N') - 1). 'D'))->format('d-m-Y');
    $eow = $od->add(new DateInterval('P6D'))->format('d-m-Y');
    $dates["$sow/$eow"][] = $d;
}
print_r($dates);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [31-12-2018/06-01-2019] => Array ( 
        [0] => 01-01-2019
        [1] => 02-01-2019
        [2] => 05-01-2019 
    )
    [21-01-2019/27-01-2019] => Array (
        [0] => 22-01-2019
    )
    [28-01-2019/03-02-2019] => Array (
        [0] => 02-02-2019
        [1] => 03-02-2019
    )
    [18-02-2019/24-02-2019] => Array (
        [0] => 24-02-2019
    )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/JBAfD)

Comment: Great Man... it's perfect